# Google Cloud SQL import in Python

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform

I'm looking at Google Cloud SQL documentation looking at how to make an import to a MySQL dump with the Python API. 
[Instances: import](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/import#examples)

The problem I have is in this line, where I get a syntax error: 

`request = service.instances().import(project=project, instance=instance, body=instances_import_request_body)`

I'm no expert, but isn't "import" a keyword? 
Should I expect Google is going to change this or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Try `import_` instead. It seems they haven't fixed that in the python sample code.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.